# How to display the error received from the API in the application?

Tags: flutter

I receive an error from the backend (API) as follows.
How can I display multiple errors in a row with text widget?

```json
{"message":{"mobile":["The mobile field format is invalid.","The mobile field must have at least 11 digits."]}}
```

Comment: just decode the json and loop through each string from mobile array

Comment: when i use jsonDecode get this error type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?'

Comment: edit the question and add your code that you have wrote

Comment: please add your code snippet which is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the API returns `multiple` errors? if so, you can either use ListView.builder to display all the errors:

```
  List errorsList = [];
  ListView.builder(
    itemCount: errorsList.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Text(errorsList[index]);
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
```

or if you want to use a text widget, you can combine all the errors together using `.join("")` and `maxLines` parameter in your `Text` widget.

```
List errorsList = [];
String errors = errorsList.join("");
```